# How to use SQL join correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the AdventureWorks database to do some SQL exercices.
I'm trying to transform my code into using the Join statement, but I cannot seem do to it correctly.

This is my code that I originally made to display the custumer name, product name,  sales amount as well as quantity and the year when It was bought:

```sql
SELECT FirstName, LastName, EnglishProductName, ProductAlternateKey, 
SUM(SalesAmount) as sales, sum(OrderQuantity) as Qty, CalendarYear 

FROM [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[FactInternetSales], 
     [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimProduct], 
     [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimCustomer], 
     [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimDate]

WHERE FirstName = 'Julia' And LastName = 'Wright' or 
      FirstName = 'Cedric' And LastName = 'Ma' or
      FirstName = 'David' and LastName = 'Rodriguez'

GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, EnglishProductName, ProductAlternateKey, CalendarYear
ORDER BY CalendarYear DESC, FirstName ASC, LastName
```

Comment: If you want to practice joins, you should use the `join` keyword. Comma separated join style is out of date (by about 30-odd years). Also, you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Note: `JOIN` is an operator, not a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You*** need to know what columns in each table relate to each other.

*(We can't tell you, because we can't see your database's design.)*

For example...

```
SELECT
    FirstName, LastName, EnglishProductName, ProductAlternateKey, 
    SUM(SalesAmount) as sales, sum(OrderQuantity) as Qty, CalendarYear 
FROM
    [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[FactInternetSales]
INNER JOIN
    [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimProduct]
        ON DimProduct.ProductID = FactInternetSale.ProductID
INNER JOIN
    [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimCustomer]
        ON DimCustomer.CustomerID = FactInternetSale.CustomerID
INNER JOIN
    [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimDate]
        ON DimDate.DateID = FactInternetSale.DateID
WHERE
    (FirstName = 'Julia'  AND LastName = 'Wright'   ) or 
    (FirstName = 'Cedric' AND LastName = 'Ma'       ) or
    (FirstName = 'David'  AND LastName = 'Rodriguez')
GROUP BY
    FirstName, LastName, EnglishProductName, ProductAlternateKey, CalendarYear
ORDER BY
    CalendarYear DESC, FirstName ASC, LastName
```

Be careful to to put the table names in front of the column names.  Like I did in the join clauses.  I can infer `FirstName` comes from `DimCustomer` but `DimCustomer.FirstName` makes it explicit and robust.